# M2DOC Calling service from interpreter

Tags: m2doc

I read that it is possible to call his own Service in the interpreter view.

I am able to call my service in my M2DOC template but i don't know how to call it from the interpreter.

My objectives is to write some services and call them in the interpreter view to make some queries on my model.

Thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 0):

There is a MS Word add-in in development that provide completion in the context of a given genconf. You can test this feature with the [nightly updatesite](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/obeo-m2doc-releases/master/nightly/repository). The documentation is available [here](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#ms-word-add-in).

Comment: Thank you but when I want to used the updatesite I have the following errors :

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: M2Doc UI Developer Resources 3.1.0.202002241623 (org.obeonetwork.m2doc.ui.feature.source.feature.group 3.1.0.202002241623) Missing requirement: M2Doc MS Word add-in 3.1.0.202002241623 (org.obeonetwork.m2doc.word.addin 3.1.0.202002241623) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jetty.server 9.4.24' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: 

How to solve i

Comment: I added jetty dependencies to the update site. The build should be finished in 30 min.

Comment: I cannot use this addin because the functionnality "catalogue d'applications approuvée" is blocked by the administrator of my laptop. Is there another solution ?

Comment: I'm not aware of an other way but I'm not an expert. You should check with your administrator.